# implementing JavaScript SDK with familiysearch Webapi Authentication

Tags: javascript

We are implementing JavaScript SDK in to our own JavaScript. While implementing it we having some problem. we are currently working as you provided link here : https://github.com/rootsdev/familysearch-javascript-sdk/ We followed the guidelines as given in the following link http://rootsdev.org/familysearch-javascript-sdk/#/api Now we are facing one problem regarding integration in our JavaScript. we can't make the object of the familysearch. we are getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: FamilySearch is not defined"